# Oracle time table - Fill in missing times

Tags: oracle

I have a query that gives me renders per minute (when there is a render during the minute)

```
select count(*) as "Total Rendered", to_char(r.request_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as "ByMinute" from form_render r where r.form_type_id = 49 
and r.request_dt >= to_timestamp('09-16-2015 08:00', 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi')
group by to_char(r.request_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
order by to_char(r.request_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') desc
```

### Total Rendered  |    ByMinute

```
 19           2015-09-17 09:31
 10           2015-09-17 09:30
  1           2015-09-17 09:28
  6           2015-09-17 09:27
 18           2015-09-17 09:25
 22           2015-09-17 09:24
 12           2015-09-17 09:23
 13           2015-09-17 09:21
 22           2015-09-17 09:20
```

However I want a row for all times (by minute) even when there were none rendered  (add rows for times when no renders occurred...09:22,09:26, 09:29)

So something like this

### Total Rendered  |    ByMinute

```
 19           2015-09-17 09:31
 10           2015-09-17 09:30
  0           2015-09-17 09:29
  1           2015-09-17 09:28
  6           2015-09-17 09:27
  0           2015-09-17 09:26
 18           2015-09-17 09:25
 22           2015-09-17 09:24
 12           2015-09-17 09:23
  0           2015-09-17 09:22
 13           2015-09-17 09:21
 22           2015-09-17 09:20
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Sean

## ===========================================================================

## Sept 20 attempt.....

===========================================================================

Thank you very much for taking the time to put this together.  SQL is definitely not my strength as I am sure you can tell!

So I have patched together the time table and my query but am getting an error  (ORA01843: not a valid month.)

When I run my query by itself

```
select count(*)as "Total_Rendered" , to_char(r.request_dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')as "ByMinute" from form_render r where r.form_type_id = 49 
and r.request_dt >= to_timestamp('09/17/2015 09:11', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') and r.request_dt <= to_timestamp('09/17/2015 09:18', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
group by to_char(r.request_dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')
order by 2 desc
```

I get the following

```
TOTAL_RENDERED |  ByMinute
---------------------------
4               |  09/17/2015 09:18
16              |  09/17/2015 09:17
4               |  09/17/2015 09:16
2               |  09/17/2015 09:11
```

When I run the minute_table query

```
WITH   min_date AS /* replace start and stop timestamp here */
   (SELECT to_date('09/17/2015 09:11', 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi') minute FROM dual
   ),
 max_date AS
   (SELECT to_date('09/17/2015 09:18', 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi') minute FROM dual
   ),  
 minute_table AS
   (SELECT
          (SELECT minute FROM min_date
     ) + (rownum -1)/(24*60) AS by_minute
   FROM dual
     CONNECT BY level <=
     (SELECT (24*60) *(
       (SELECT minute FROM max_date
       ) -
       (SELECT minute FROM min_date
       ))+1
     FROM dual
     )
   )
select * from minute_table
```

I get the following....

```
9/17/2015 9:11:00 AM
9/17/2015 9:12:00 AM
9/17/2015 9:13:00 AM
9/17/2015 9:14:00 AM
9/17/2015 9:15:00 AM
9/17/2015 9:16:00 AM
9/17/2015 9:17:00 AM
9/17/2015 9:18:00 AM
```

so far so good.

When I combine the two queries to get this query

```
WITH   min_date AS /* replace start and stop timestamp here */
   (SELECT to_date('09/17/2015 09:11', 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') minute FROM dual
   ),
 max_date AS
   (SELECT to_date('09/17/2015 09:18', 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') minute FROM dual
   ),  
 minute_table AS
   (SELECT
          (SELECT minute FROM min_date
     ) + (rownum -1)/(24*60) AS by_minute
   FROM dual
     CONNECT BY level <=
     (SELECT (24*60) *(
       (SELECT minute FROM max_date
       ) -
       (SELECT minute FROM min_date
       ))+1
     FROM dual
     )
   ),
 tbl AS
   (
   select count(*)as "Total_Rendered" , to_char(r.request_dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')as "ByMinute" from form_render r where r.form_type_id = 49 
   and r.request_dt >= to_timestamp('09/17/2015 09:11', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') and r.request_dt <= to_timestamp('09/17/2015 09:18', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
   group by to_char(r.request_dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')
   order by 2 desc
   )
 SELECT minute_table.by_minute ,
   NVL(tbl."Total_Rendered",'0') AS total_rendered
 FROM minute_table
 left OUTER JOIN tbl
 ON tbl."ByMinute" = minute_table.by_minute 
 order by 1 desc
 ;
```

I get an error ORA01843: not a valid month.

I am not entirely certain why the error is occuring but I am confident it has to do with the format differences between the columns I am joining on?
 The format of the dates in the time table vs my table are likely the cause but I am not certain.

Time Table has 9/17/2015 9:11:00 AM  and 
 my query has 09/17/2015 09:11   (notice missing leading zero on Month, seconds and AM)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks again for your time and expertise....
 Sean

Comment: Oracle has a partition join functionality for this.

Comment: Partition join would be helpful only if there are other columns selected from outer joined table, in this case you have nothing to partition by.

Comment: Sorry, Was offline for most of yesterday.  Oracle version 10g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly different solution without dependency on 12c and with "parameters" for start and stop minutes.

```
 WITH   min_date AS /* replace start and stop timestamp here */
   (SELECT to_date('2015-09-17 09:28','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') minute FROM dual
   ),
 max_date AS
   (SELECT to_date('2015-09-17 09:31','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') minute FROM dual
   ),  
 minute_table AS
   (SELECT
          (SELECT minute FROM min_date
     ) + (rownum -1)/(24*60) AS by_minute
   FROM dual
     CONNECT BY level <=
     (SELECT (24*60) *(
       (SELECT minute FROM max_date
       ) -
       (SELECT minute FROM min_date
       ))+1
     FROM dual
     )
   ),
 tbl AS
   (SELECT 19 Total_Rendered,
     to_date('2015-09-17 09:31','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') By_Minute
   FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,to_date('2015-09-17 09:30','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 19,to_date('2015-09-17 09:28','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') FROM dual
   )
 SELECT minute_table.by_minute ,
   NVL(tbl.total_rendered,'0') AS total_rendered
 FROM minute_table
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl
 ON tbl.By_Minute = minute_table.by_minute 
 ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to put this together.  SQL is definitlely not my strength as I am sure you can tell!

Answer (score 1):

So this is working in Oracle 12c. But you have to change it for your use.

```
           with tbl(Total_Rendered, ByMinute) as (
                  select 19,to_date('2015-09-17 09:31','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') from dual union all
                   select 1,to_date('2015-09-17 09:30','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') from dual union all
                   select 19,to_date('2015-09-17 09:28','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') from dual )

          select nvl(tbl.total_rendered,'0') as total_rendered,by_minute from              
                    (select to_date('2015-09-17 09:28','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') + (1/24/60) * column_value as by_minute from 
                    TABLE(  CAST( MULTISET( SELECT LEVEL FROM   DUAL
                                        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
                              ) )) time_range
                    left outer join
                       tbl
                              on tbl.ByMinute = time_range.by_minute
```

Output

```
        TOTAL_RENDERED BY_MINUTE
        0   17-SEP-2015 09:29:00
        1   17-SEP-2015 09:30:00
        19  17-SEP-2015 09:31:00
```

What I did is first I am using a temporary table tbl which will have data as your input. Then I generated timestamp from '17-SEP-2015 09:29:00' -  '17-SEP-2015 09:31:00'to generate a time_range

Now I did a left outer join from this time_range to tbl which has missing data. For the rows not in tbl, I am printing 0.

You can use this query and edit it to get the time_range and join with your data to get this output.